# how to calculate grade results in php

Tags: php

this code calclate normal result
example

- if 1200 marks of student then showing a grade
- if 1100 marks of student then showing a nothing
- if 800 marks of student then showing b grade

but i want like this

- if marks is 1200 then showing a grade
- if marks is less then 1200 then grade showing b
- if marks is less then 800 then showing grade c

how can i do this please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

```
<?php
    $calculate="$marks";
    switch ($calculate)
    {
    case "1200":
       echo "A";
       break;
    case "800":
       echo "B!";
       break;
    case "600":
       echo "C";
       break;
    default:
       echo "";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$calculate = $marks;

if ($calculate < 800) {
    echo "C";
} else if ($calculate < 1200) {
    echo "B!";
} else if ($calculate == 1200) {
    echo "A";
}
?>
```